# Programatically create additional cloud task queues from pub sub triggered cloud functions

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-tasks

Using cloud functions to schedule cloud tasks, upon scheduled time the cloud task triggers an HTTP end point. As of now created a single queue with the following configuration.
Max dispatches per second:500
Max concurrent dispatches :1000
Max attempts: 5

The cloud function is pub sub triggered. In a second pub sub may be receiving 10000 messages and in turn the cloud function scales and will be creating 10000 tasks.

**Question:**
If the scaled cloud functions has to create more tasks and assign it to different queues , how best the cloud function has to decide and create queues and assign tasks to different queues considering cold and warm queues capabilities to avoid latency.

I read through this official doc, but it is not so clear for dummies https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/manage-cloud-task-scaling#queue

Comment: Why do you want to create new queues? On which parameter?

Comment: in cloud task max dispatches per second is 500. If i get more messages from pub sub more tasks will be created inside the cloud function. If queue can not handle that extra new task it will be discarded, right?
I saw in one of the google cloud discussions , queue can run out of tokens. correct me if I am wrong. 
To simply put what happens if i create more than 500 tasks from multiple cloud instances to one task queue in a second?

Comment: The max dispatch is the max number of request that Cloud Task can perform in 1 seconds. Therefore is you set more that 500 task that should be run at the same second, some will be delayed, but not discarded. However, you can stack more than 500 tasks per queue, and create up to 6 millions of tasks per minute. The question here: will you have more than 500 task to run (dispatch) in the same second?

Comment: I thought task will be discarded. thanks.
we are getting data asynchronously form the AMQP system from million customers which triggers the pub sub. I think it may be possible we will get 500 messages per second(i did not check though). wanted to confirm.
By delay you mean, when any of the 500 task completed the 501 task will picked up by the queue?

Comment: Yes, and you can't have more than 1000 task active in the same time by queue (imagine that your task takes 10 seconds. The first second 500 task are trigger, the 2nd second, 500 more, then nothing during 8 seconds, the duration of the 500 first to complete and free this quota limit.)

Comment: if all this tasks are time sensitive, means it can tolerate only 2-5 seconds delay, what should be done? here comes the original question again, creating additional queues by some logic and assign the tasks, if an existing queue can not execute this task immediately .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Back to your original question, if your process is time sensitive and you need to trigger more than 500 requests at the same time, you need to create additional queues (as mentioned in the documentation)

To dispatch the AMQP messages in several queues, you need to define the number of queue that you need and a sharding key. If you have a numerical ID, you can use the modulo X (X is the number of queue) as key and use the corresponding queue name. You can also use a hash or your data.

In your process, if the queue exists, add a task to it, or create it, and add it then. In any case, you can't have more than 1000 queues.

Comment: Thanks, will try and post the results here. 

is it good approach to use get task counts in the available queue, if it is exceeding 1000, create new queue on the go and assign new tasks to it?

Comment: No, because the task can be added to the queue but not trigger in the same time. Or the other way round to create 1000 tasks to trigger in the same time in the same queue. My idea is to create a random dispatch to minimise/remove/avoid the hotspots